# How to check if I have something to read on a StreamReader?

Tags: c#, sockets, streamreader

I need to check if my client has something in the buffer so I did not wait to write it.

```
private async void ThreadMethod_ListenClient()
    {
        while (true) {
            if (ClientQueue.Count == 0)
                continue;
            Client client = (Client)ClientQueue.Dequeue ();
            if (client.Reader != null) {
                string Say = await client.Reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (Say != null) {
                    if (Say.Length != 0) {
                        Console.WriteLine (Say);
                    }
                }
            }
            ClientQueue.Enqueue (client);

        }
    }
```

client.Reader : StreamReader from TcpClient

client.Socket : TcpClient

How to check if 'client.Reader' empty?

obs. C# with Mono

Comment: `if (Say != null)` answers your own question!

Answer (score 4):

Also `StreamReader.Peek()` which returns `-1` when end of file is reached or when there's nothing to read.
Can be checked as follows:

```
while(StreamReader.Peek() != -1){
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: He is still waiting :(

Comment: I don't understand?
Of course in your case you'll use 'client.Reader.Peek()' instead of StreamReader.Peek()

Answer (score 2):

> How to check if I have something to read on a StreamReader?

I don't know for `StreamReader`, but for `TcpClient` you can use `TcpClient.GetStream()` method which returns `NetworkStream` which in turn has [DataAvailable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This is explained in the **Remarks** section of the `TcpClient.GetStream` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can avoid blocking on a read operation by checking the DataAvailable property.

**Edit:** I've posted this because your code is running into a specific domain. While the general approach described in other answers/comments work for normal finite streams (like `FileStream`, `MemoryStream` etc.), it doesn't work for infinite streams like `NetworkStream`.

Comment: StreamReader a = new StreamReader (client.GetStream ( )) made a StreamReader for this socket. I am only working on StreamReader :)

Comment: But still underlying `Stream` is a `NetworkStream`. `StreamReader` is just an abstraction on top of the stream.

Comment: Slow? `((NetworkStream)client.Reader.BaseStream).DataAvailable`

Comment: Yes... A make a NetworkStream on Client class for dont get everytime... But this dont show all lines now :(

Comment: Well, the above just answers your question **how** to check. It doesn't mean you have to use it - your code is perfect for a listener, and `async/await` do the necessary magic to make it efficient. It's similar to message loop - you can check if there is a message in the message queue, but if there isn't at this time, that doesn't mean there will not be in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

[`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns `null` if the end of stream has reached or if there is nothing left to read. So, you can check for that to verify whether there is anything to read or not.

```
if (client.Reader != null && client.Reader.ReadLine() != null)
```

Comment: string Say = await client.Reader.ReadLineAsync () != null;
if (Say != null) {...}

It already checks